# Fill DTO models with entities values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following DTO:

```
public class EbookDTO {
  public Int32 EbookId { get; set; }
  public Int32 CoverId { get; set; }
  public Int32 DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following Entity Framework entities:

```
public class EbookFile {
  public Int32 EbookId { get; set; }
  public Int32 FileId { get; set; }

  public virtual Ebook Ebook { get; set; }
  public virtual File File { get; set; }
}

public class File {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 EbookFileId { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual EbookFile EbookFile { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following `EbookDTO` list:

```
List<EbookDTO> ebooks = new List<EbookDTO>() {
  new EbookDTO { Id = 1 },
  new EbookDTO { Id = 2 }
}
```

I need, for each of these ebooks, to get their DocumentId and CoverId:

1. In contexts.EbooksFiles get the ones that has `Ebook.Id` = `DTO.EbookId;`
2. From(1) take the Files Ids of each `EbookFile`;
3. Find in `context.Files` the ones that has the Ids taken in (2);
4. Each `EbookDTO` `DocumentId` would be the file with name "Document" and the `EbookDTO` `CoverId` would be the file with name Cover.

I tried a few queries such as:

```
context
  .EbooksFiles
  .Where(x => ebooks.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.EbookId))
```

But I am not sure how to test the file name, get its id and add define the `DocumentId` and `CoverId` of each `EbookDTO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this harder than necessary by starting the query from `EbookFile`. There are multiple `EbookFile`s for one `Ebook`, so you'd need some form of grouping to collect the two records you need to build one `EbookDTO`.

If you start the query from `Ebook`, this grouping is provided naturally:

```
var ebookIds = ebooks.Select(y => y.Id).ToArray();

from eb in context.Ebooks
where ebookIds.Contains(eb.EbookId)
select new EbookDTO
{
    EbookId = eb.EbookId,
    CoverId = eb.EbookFiles.FirstOrDefault(ebf => ebf.File.Name == "Cover").FileId,
    DocumentId = eb.EbookFiles.FirstOrDefault(ebf => ebf.File.Name == "Document").FileId,
}
```

I'm assuming that this navigation property `EbookFiles` exists in `Ebook`, otherwise I'd recommend to create it.